# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated / AJAX & API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to create an ajax function with the MailChimp list API however I am facing the following error 'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects '.  PHP code works fine but when I try to introduce ajax it all goes wrong.

Honestly, I don't know where to start with this as have little experience in using ajax with API.

Could someone please be kind enough to review the below code and give me their thoughts?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subCard").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var emailSub = $("#emailSub").val();
      var fNameSub = $("#fNameSub").val();
      var lNameSub = $("#lNameSub").val();
      var subSubmit = $("#subSubmit").val();
    $(".form-message").load("action.php", {
      emailSub: emailSub,
      fNameSub: fNameSub,
      lNameSub: lNameSub,
      subSubmit: subSubmit
    });  
  });
});


<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['subSubmit'])){
  $emailSub = $_POST['emailSub'];
  $fNameSub = $_POST['fNameSub'];
  $lNameSub = $_POST['lNameSub'];
if(!empty($emailSub) && !filter_var($emailSub, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
    // MailChimp API credentials
    $apiKey = 'user API key';
    $listID = 'user list ID';

    // MailChimp API URL
    $memberID = md5(strtolower($emailSub));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
    $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

    // member information
    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $emailSub,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'  => [
            'FNAME'     => $fNameSub,
            'LNAME'     => $lNameSub
        ]
    ]);

    // send a HTTP POST request with curl
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    // store the status message based on response code
    if ($httpCode == 200) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #ffffff">You have successfully subscribed to AquaCodeStudio.</p>';
    } else {
        switch ($httpCode) {
            case 214:
                $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                break;
            default:
                $msg = 'Sorry a problem occurred, please try again.';
                break;
        }
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">'.$msg.'</p>';
    }
    }else{
       $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter a valid email address.</p>';
    }
}
// redirect to homepage
header('location:about.php');

?>
```

Comment: The code you've provided won't give the effect you described. Perhaps you have an ajaxSetup call somewhere you aren't showing us. You need to provide a [mcve]. Your code doesn't appear to be minimal nor complete.

Comment: where is the ajax function?

Comment: Sorry people very new to this so probably making many rookie mistakes!  I thought the  $(".form-message").load("action.php", { function is the Ajax side of things.  I have used the about jquery code before in another form and worked as expected (without API though).  Feel like I'm in a very large and dark room with this so would be grateful if someone could shed some light :)

Comment: Yes, [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is AJAX - but is should not be synchronous unless that was explicitly configured somewhere.

Comment: That the PHP part still redirects to the about.php page after processing the POST data - is that intentional, or an oversight?

Comment: @misorude funny enough when I remove that piece of code it works, admittedly not to perfection, however it has removed the error message and is delivering the content.  Thank you!  I assume this was not working due to ajax conflicting with header('location:about.php'); syntax?

Comment: It actually redirects the AJAX request in the background - so first the data is send to load.php and processed there, and then the browser makes another (GET) request for `about.php`. What is then inserted into your original document is the content of the latter. Not sure how exactly this causes the “Synchronous…” warning, but maybe that page itself contains code that makes AJAX requests again, or something like that. (.load, when executed without a suffixed selector expression, executes <script> elements contained in the loaded HTML automatically.)

Comment: @misorude makes a lot of sense and thanks for taking the time to explain, really helps.  If you want to mark this down as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load` in itself is synchronous, unless something else is specified in the global jQuery AJAX settings.

The redirect to the `about.php` page after processing the form data seems to be the culprit here.

It actually redirects the AJAX request in the background - so first the data is send to `load.php` and processed there, and then the browser makes another (GET) request for `about.php`. What is then inserted into your original document is the content of the latter. Not sure how exactly this causes the “Synchronous…” warning, but maybe that page itself contains code that makes AJAX requests again, or something like that. (`.load`, when executed without a suffixed selector expression, executes `<script>` elements contained in the loaded HTML automatically.)